# Django ModelForm: Making an "Other" Textarea manditory when the user selects "Other" from RadioSelect

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am converting a survey from a Form to a ModelForm in Django 1.6.2. I want to create an "Other" `forms.Textarea` which the user has to fill out if they select "Other" from the `forms.RadioSelect`. I want this to be mandatory only if the user selects "Other" from the `forms.RadioSelect`.

This is my code so far, it submits fine but the `forms.Textarea` is not mandatory. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks

If I remove the `blank=True,` from `party_benefit_message` the `forms.Textarea` is mandatory on every `forms.RadioSelect` selection.

**models.py**

```
PARTY_BENEFIT = (
    ('NO', 'No'),
    ('YES_DEMOCRAT', 'Yes, Democrat'),
    ('YES_REPUBLICAN', 'Yes, Republican'),
    ('YES_OTHER', 'Other') )   
party_benefit = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, default=None, choices=PARTY_BENEFIT, verbose_name="Does one or another political party benefit more than the others due to Biased coverage in the media? \n And if so which?")
party_benefit_message = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, verbose_name='If you selected \"Other\", please specify:')

def clean_other(self):
    cleaned_data = super(SurveyFormG, self).clean()
    if 'party_benefit' in cleaned_data.keys():
      options = cleaned_data['party_benefit']
      if 'party_benefit_message' in options:
        other_input = cleaned_data['party_benefit_message']
        if other_input == None or len(other_input) == 0:
          raise forms.ValidationError('Required when \"Other\" is checked')

    return cleaned_data
```

**forms.py**

```
class SurveyFormG(forms.ModelForm): #Reflective Questions

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['party_benefit', 'party_benefit_message']        

        widgets = {'party_benefit' : forms.RadioSelect,
                   'party_benefit_message' : forms.Textarea}
```

Any help would be great appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a custom clean method on you model (rather than on your form to make this validation more reusable) :

**models.py**

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Person(models.Model):

    PARTY_BENEFIT = (
        ('NO', 'No'),
        ('YES_DEMOCRAT', 'Yes, Democrat'),
        ('YES_REPUBLICAN', 'Yes, Republican'),
        ('YES_OTHER', 'Other')
    )   
    party_benefit = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, default=None, choices=PARTY_BENEFIT, verbose_name="Does one or another political party benefit more than the others due to Biased coverage in the media? \n And if so which?")
    party_benefit_message = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, verbose_name='If you selected \"Other\", please specify:')

    def clean(self):
        if self.party_benefit == 'YES_OTHER' and not self.party_benefit_message:
            raise ValidationError({'party_benefit_message': ['You must enter a message.']})
```

More info on model validation here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

You form does not change.

Comment: Thanks so much. Two things though. It should be `forms.ValidationError`. If I use the dict `{'party_benefit_message': 'You must enter a message.'}`  the message prints out in a vertical column. Any ideas?

Comment: No it is not forms.ValidationError since you are in the model !

Comment: What do you mean by 'prints out in a vertical column' ?

Comment: If I dont use forms.ValidationError it raises an error "global name 'ValidationError' is not defined". A vertical. column as if I hit return after each letter

Comment: Re-read the answer ;-)  you have to import ValidationError from django.core.exceptions. Also you validation lives in you models.py file to make it more reusable.

Comment: If it prints vertically, change your validation error to this : {'party_benefit_message': ['You must enter a message.']}

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this (`clean` method inside your `ModelForm`):

```
def clean(self):
    benefit_option = self.cleaned_data.get('party_benefit')
    message = self.cleaned_data.get('party_benefit_message')
    if benefit_option and benefit_option == 'YES_OTHER' and message is None:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Message is required when \"Other\" is checked')
```

Comment: It is better to write the clean method in the model to make it more reusable. Indeed when calling form.is_valid(), the clean() method of the model is called.

Comment: @Charlesthk I have never used it, skipped it somehow.  Shame on me I guess )

Comment: That's ok ;-), also, to attach a ValidationError to a specific field, you have to  pass a dict {'field': 'error'} !